# Qt how to properly do a screensaver function windows C++

Tags: c++, windows, qt, screensaver

I have to do an touchscreen app for windows, and if the customer hasnt click for 60sec on the screen, a little video or advertsing appears (and leave right after the customer's clik).

I've already made my own thread function for that (a simple loop with a usleep), but i dont think its a good way.

I'm seeking for an obj or something else with Qt that could be better, any ideas?

Comment: Please choose one of C and C++.

Comment: Ok : C++


Now, why, aint both are possible??

Comment: You have to pick a language and we give answers for that language. Due to a lot of people abusing this, you cannot choose more than one language. In the past there have been numerous questions where someone said “C/C++ is okay”, then I gave an answer in C and it was rejected by OP because it wasn't written in C++.

Comment: Yeah ok, i've started by C so for me C == C++, MB

Comment: This is exactly the kind of ignorant mindset that led us to not allowing people to ask C/C++ questions: C is not equal to C++ and neither is C a subset of C++. There are many correct and interesting C programs that don't compile as C++.

Comment: I know ty, but as i'am in C++ so all the C way is possible that's what i meant, but thats not the point.

Comment: No! When you are C++, there are C constructs that are *not* usable because C++ doesn't have them. Please read about the differences between C and C++ before making incorrect claims like these.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but it sounds like you want to listen to [QTMouseEvents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmouseevent.html). Specifically it sounds like you'll be interested in events of type QEvent::MouseButtonPress. Start a timer on a click, once it reaches 60 seconds (note: reset the timer on each click) then start playing the video. Another event of that type will then allow you to 'restore' the main window app (if the video is playing)

Comment: I'll check for that QEvent::MouseButtonPress way ty